# проверка схождение суммы ряда с точностью эпсилон, C#

Tags: c#, ряды

есть вообщем вот такое задание.

[image: задание]

Интересует правильно ли его решил (ниже код).

Не совсем понятно как правильно сделать графическую интерпретацию, нужно выводить каждый шаг сумму? И откуда брать "y"? Для графики хочу использовать "ZedGraph".

```
double x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox_X.Text);
double eps = Convert.ToDouble(textBox_eps.Text);

double n = 1, f = 1;
double sum = f;

while (Math.Abs(f)>eps)
 {
   n++;
   f *= Math.Pow(x, n) / ((n + 2) * Math.Pow(2, n));
   sum += f;
 }
```

Comment: Мне кажется при x < 2 сумма не сходится. Это неважно?
Установите n = 0 в начале ИЛИ переместите n++ в конец цикла и вычисление суммы будет верным.

Answer (score 1):

Данный ряд не сходится, если строго `x > 2` (можете проверить [вольфрамом](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)). Т. е. нужно добавить условие:

```cs
if (x > 2)
{
    sum = double.PositiveInfinity;
}
```

Можно было использовать хитрые штуковины и вычислить сумму без циклов, но мне кажется ваш препод офигеет, поэтому...:

```cs
var x = double.Parse(textX.Text);
var eps = Math.Abs(double.Parse(textEps.Text));

double f(double n) =>
    Math.Pow(x, n) /
    ((n + 2D) * Math.Pow(2D, n));

var sum = 0D;
var n = 1D;
double y;

if (x > 2D && eps <= 0.01D) // ряд расходится и eps достаточно мало
{
    sum = double.PositiveInfinity;

    do
    {
        y = f(n++);

        // вставить код для построения графика
    } while (n < graphLength); 
}
else // ряд сходится или eps не достаточно мало
{
    double dy;
    var py = f(n); // previous y
    var isOutOfBounds = false;

    do
    {
        y = f(++n);
        dy = y - py;
        py = y;
        sum += y;

        if (n <= graphLength)
        {
            // вставить код для построения графика

            isOutOfBounds = true;
        }
    } while (dy > eps ||
             !isOutOfBounds);
}

return sum;
```

---

`isOutOfBounds` - это моя горе оптимизация, чтоб не чекать постоянно `n < graphLength`.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем я так решил задачу)

юзал библиотеку "zedgraph" для графика, проверку на сходимость ряда сделал если сумма уходит в + бесконечность)

прикрепляю весь листинг, мб кому нибудь пригодится :)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZedGraph;

namespace lab_MVMPO
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Создадим список точек
        private PointPairList list = new PointPairList();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.Title.Text = "Сумма ряда: x^n/((n+2)*2^n)";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox_X.Text=="")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Введите значение X", "Предупреждение", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                textBox_X.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if (textBox_eps.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Введите значение e", "Предупреждение", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                textBox_eps.Focus();
                return;
            }

            double x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox_X.Text);
            double eps = Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(textBox_eps.Text));

            if (eps > 0.1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Точность указана неверно.", "Предупреждение", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                return;
            }

            double n = 1, f = 1;
            double sum = 0;

            list.Clear();

            while (Math.Abs(f)>eps)
            {
                f *= Math.Pow(x, n) / ((n + 2) * Math.Pow(2, n));
                sum += f;
                list.Add(n,sum);
                n++;

                if (double.IsInfinity(sum))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ряд не сходится. +inf", "Результат", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    cleargraph();
                    textBox_sum.Text = "";
                    return;
                }                
            }

            textBox_sum.Text = sum.ToString();

            drawgraph();
        }

        // очистка графика
        public void cleargraph()
        {
            zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
            zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Clear();
            zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
        }

        // нарисовать график
        public void drawgraph()
        {
            cleargraph();

            GraphPane panel = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

            // Очистим список кривых на тот случай, если до этого сигналы уже были нарисованы
            panel.CurveList.Clear();

            // Интервал, где есть данные
            double xmin = -10;
            double xmax = 10;

            double xmin_limit = -10;
            double xmax_limit = 10;

            double ymin_limit = -10;
            double ymax_limit = 10.0;

            list.Insert(0,0,0);
            LineItem myCurve = panel.AddCurve("Сумма ряда: x^n/((n+2)*2^n)", list, Color.Green, SymbolType.Circle);

            // Устанавливаем интересующий нас интервал по оси X
            panel.XAxis.Scale.Min = xmin_limit;
            panel.XAxis.Scale.Max = xmax_limit;

            // Устанавливаем интересующий нас интервал по оси Y
            panel.YAxis.Scale.Min = ymin_limit;
            panel.YAxis.Scale.Max = ymax_limit;

            zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
            zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
        }

        // проверка ввода
        private void textBox_X_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            char number = e.KeyChar;
            if ((e.KeyChar <= 47 || e.KeyChar >= 58) && number != 8 && number != 44 && number!=45)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```